# Colour Critical Graph Proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a simple graph. We call $G$ colour-critical if
$\chi(G) > \chi(G\setminus v)$ for all $v \in V$.
Prove that if $G$ is colour-critical with $\chi(G) = k$, then $d(v) \geq k − 1$ for all $v \in V$.

Can someone please explain to me how this proof is shown, as I am genuinely stuck and have no clue as to how to do this proof?

Comment: Please add the [self-study] tag & read its wiki.

Answer (score 1):

For any $v\in V$, $G\setminus v$ has a proper colouring with $k-1$ colours. Now suppose there is a vertex $v\in V$ with $d(v)\leq k-2$. Take a colouring of $G\setminus v$ using $k-1$ colours. Since $d(v)\leq k-2$, one of the $k-1$ colours is *not* used amongst the neighbours of $v$. Colour $v$ with this colour to produce a colouring of $G$ using at most $k-1$ colours. This contradicts the assumption that $\chi(G)=k$.